# Jquery Custom width draggable

Tags: jquery

I am currently developing right now a site like this:
http://www.windowshop.com/

It's engine will be magento but the main problem is the UI portion. I knew that the windowshop is based on flash. The problem is I would like to build this using html4 with html5 elements roughly.

I couldn't find a jquery that will handle the overflowing navigation of our catalogs. We have 11 categories under the top navigation. I couldn't use a width 100% to accommodate all the nav items, just like from windowshop.com, the nav overflow can be scrolled by sides.

Please help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far?  Is the site viewable anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I recently started to replicate UX / UI of Windowshop using the [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) Jquery plug-in.